# Why do only either 2 of 3 trees or 1 tree show material?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor

I'm new to Blender. I tried to add materials to all 3 trees but it's only either two trees or the other one tree that shows a material.

[image]

I added some nodes to all of them but only 2 trees show material. When I duplicate the same node system and plug it into another *Material Output* node, only 1 tree shows a material.

How do I fix this node setup so that all 3 trees show a material?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You need to add a new material slot (Box on right with plus + button). Hit the plus on side to add a new material slot, press plus below to assign material to that slot. You cannot have 2 material outputs for a single material - each new material needs its own slot and graph.